# bash show for loop variable twice

Tags: bash, bsd

Why does this only show the entry from `data.csv` one time?

```
for i in `cat ~/Downloads/data.csv`
do
  echo $i $i
done
```

I have tried `$i$i` and the `+=` operator and none of them seem to do what I would have expected.  The goal is to create links from data.csv, which is a list of urls.  So the output would ideally be

```
<a href='$i'>$i</a>
```

I am using OSX.

Comment: See [Bash FAQ 001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for the correct way to iterate over the contents of a file.

Comment: Your CSV file probably has DOS line endings, so the carriage return in the variable value causes the second one to overwrite the first.

Comment: I'm sure you know that already, but it's maybe also a good hint for others: Caution on the output of `'$i'`. The single quotes have to be escaped or double quotes should be used to resolve variable correctly.

Comment: @chepner Would you please make your comment  into an answer? That was indeed the root cause of my trouble.  Thanks to other posters though for improving my lazy `for` loop use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use `bash` for file content processing, `awk` is better suited for this.

```
$ awk '{print "<a href=\"" $0 "\">" $0 "</a>"}' file
```